# Rescaling list with negative entries using limits with same absolute value

Tags: list-manipulation, numerics

Suppose I have a list of both positive and negative numbers:

```
list = {3, 0, -4, 15, 0.006, -1}
```

I want to rescale the function over the range $[-1, 1]$. However, simply inputting

```
rescList = Rescale[list, {Min@list, Max@list}, {-1, 1}]
```

would not give the desired result:

```
{-0.263158, -0.578947, -1., 1., -0.578316, -0.684211}
```

The values 15 and -4 would be equidistant in this scaling. Plus, positive values would become negative.

A working solution would be to find the maximum in absolute value and rescale with respect to that:

```
absMax = Max[Abs@list];
rescList = Rescale[list, {-absMax, absMax}, {-1, 1}]
```

But I was wondering if a solution is possible without this intermediate step (and, of course, without making the code too bulky by, say, something like `rescList = Rescale[list, {-Max[Abs@list], Max[Abs@list]}, {-1, 1}]`).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your apparent target, `rescList`, is equivalent to:

```
list / Max@Abs@list
```

This can be symbolically derived from `Rescale`

```
Rescale[a, {-m, m}, {-1, 1}]
```

> ```
> a/m
> ```

Also equivalent:

```
Normalize[list, Max@*Abs]

Rescale[Abs@list]*Sign[list]

Normalize[list, Norm[#, ∞] &]  (* thanks to J. M. *)
```

Comment: Thank you, I still can't believe how I hadn't thought about just dividing by the max value. Anyway, I guess my question was more about "removing" the need for `Max@Abs` inside the code (to make it look better?). But I guess it's not really necessary.

Comment: @Enzo I'm sorry if this answer isn't satisfying.  I'm not really sure what you're seeking.  I added a form that uses `Rescale` and does away with `Max`, in case that is of some interest to you.  I don't see how you can eliminate `Abs` in a non-contrived way as that seems intrinsic to your definition.

Comment: I wasn't criticizing your answer, I'm sorry if I gave that impression. In fact, it is exactly what I was looking for. My "issue" with `Max` and `Abs` was a purely aesthetical one, I was hoping for, maybe, some `Rescale` argument for that (Something like, for example, `Rescale[x, Absolute]` which I just made up). Just my mind wandering about, I'm afraid.

Comment: @Enzo Ah, I see, no problem. :-)

Comment: `Normalize[list, Norm[#, ∞] &]` ought to work as well.

Comment: @J.M. Added; thanks.